# Random Freezes on my Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I've been having issues with my PC. I've lately added new parts to my rig and now I am constantly getting random freezes which i then have to manually restart my PC. These freezes occur at random times which makes it harder to find out what it is. Whether it is software or hardware related.

New parts I added:

- Motherboard: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. MAXIMUS VIII EXTREME
- Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti
- Ram DDR4: VENGEANCE LPX 32GB 3000MHz
- CPU: Intel Core i7 6700K @ 4.00GHz
- Cooler: CORSAIR H110i GTX
- SSD: SAMSUNG 950 PRO M.2

I have tried contacting Microsoft but they asked me to just update my windows, which my PC was already up-to-date.

Besides the random freezes, when i check event viewer, i am getting a lot of errors. I am losing my mind trying to sort this out. (Unable to attach another link)

I will try my best to upload or provide a link to give the necessary details of my PC and errors.

PC SPECS

- Operating System             Windows 10 Home 64-bit
- CPU          Intel Core i7 6700K @ 4.00GHz   30 °C           Skylake 14nm Technology
- RAM
          32.0GB Dual-Channel Unknown @ 1071MHz (15-15-15-36)
- Motherboard          ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. MAXIMUS VIII EXTREME
  (LGA1151)    28 °C
- Graphics             24EA53 (1920x1080@60Hz)             24EA53 (1920x1080@60Hz)
          24EA53 (1920x1080@60Hz)             2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti
  (NVIDIA) 35 °C
- Storage          1863GB Seagate ST2000DM001-1CH164 (SATA)    33 °C           1863GB
  Western Digital WDC WD2003FZEX-00Z4SA0 (SATA)    36 °C           232GB Samsung
  SSD 840 EVO 250GB (SSD)  24 °C           232GB Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB
  (SSD)    24 °C           238GB NVMe Samsung SSD 950 SCSI Disk Device (Unknown)
- Optical Drives           ATAPI iHAS124 E SCSI CdRom Device
- Audio            Realtek High Definition Audio

Dumpfiles: https://www.dropbox.com/s/si3udrst8sv4fo6/memorydumps.zip?dl=0

(download button takes a few seconds to show up but its on the very top right of the screen)

If you can help me out, that would be amazing!

Comment: Your title should not be `Can anyone analyse my memory-dump files?`. A more appropriate title would be `Random Freezes on my Windows 10 PC`. Also, you could say which parts you added to your rig to narrow down the buggy component. It would be useful if you gave your opinions as we don't know what exactly is happening. A screenshot would nice. Having said all this, *I am not the one who gave you a `-1`.*

Comment: Sorry about that, kind of new to this sort of stuff. Wasn't too sure what to write tbh, I will remember this for next time. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

According to the dmp, the issues come from tcpip.sys

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, A single DPC or ISR exceeded its time allotment. The offending
    component can usually be identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000000501, The DPC time count (in ticks).
Arg3: 0000000000000500, The DPC time allotment (in ticks).
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.494.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160630-1736

BIOS_VERSION:  0907

BIOS_DATE:  10/01/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  MAXIMUS VIII EXTREME

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev 1.x

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  SINGLE_DPC_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: fa8

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 39'00000000 (cache) 39'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8009c5902d1 to fffff8009c54e940

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!KeClockInterruptNotify
03 hal!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine
04 nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine
05 nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw
06 nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw
07 nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire
08 nt!KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel
09 tcpip!TcpProcessExpiredTcbTimers
0a tcpip!TcpPeriodicTimeoutHandler
0b nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs
0c nt!KiRetireDpcList
0d nt!KiIdleLoop
```

, so update network card drivers and all network related software (Antivirus, firewall, traffic capture tools, Virtual Maschine tools)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i will try and update all the drivers manually and see if it works.

Comment: I have the same problem an error, but this is not working for me either

Comment: @AbAppletic create a new question and also share the dmp files